# Selenium 3.141.59 with java in red hat 7.7 can't create new chrome driver

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Getting the following error message: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

The same code works well in my local mac, but when it is deployed to red hat, it cannot create the chrome driver.

selenium dependencies in pom xml

```
<!-- Selenium Driver Dependencies-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.33.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.28.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the method that gets the chrome driver:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


@PostConstruct
public void setChromDriverLocation(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", this.chromeDriverLocation);
}

public WebDriver getChromeDriver(Long timeoutInSeconds){
    this.LOGGER.info(String.format("Preparing to retrieve chrome driver %s", this.chromeDriverLocation));
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("headless");
    options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
    if(StringUtils.hasText(this.chromeBinaryPath)){
        this.LOGGER.info(String.format("Setting binary path %s", this.chromeBinaryPath));
        options.setBinary(this.chromeBinaryPath);
    }
    this.LOGGER.info("Getting chrome driver");
    WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    this.LOGGER.info("Successfully retrieved chrome driver");
    return chromeDriver;
}
```

It fails on the following line: WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);

google-chrome version: Google Chrome 81.0.4044.138
and the chrome driver for the same version is installed.

the chrome driver executes fine and

Please let me know of any solutions or missing dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has a similar issue. The problem was an old library of google guava was setup at the $PATH on the server, causing the issue mentioned above.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Once the dependency was taken out of the path, the below was all that was needed to run the selenium driver.

```
<!-- Selenium Driver Dependencies-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

In case someone else has the above issue, check you classpath for dependency issues and make sure that old google guave libraries are not part of your classpath.